# Cocoa HUD panel shows again after calling orderOut:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using a NSPanel with HUD style to display some information.

There's a button inside the HUD panel, when the user clicks the button, I'll open a new window  by calling:

```
[anotherWindowController showWindow:self];
[anotherWindowController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront];
```

And I want the panel disappear when the window shows, so I set the delegate of the main window, and in the `windowDidResignMain` callback, I called `[hudPanel orderOut:nil]`.

The HUD panel did disappear (I can see it), but right after it closed, it reopens.

I've checked all possible `orderFront:` code, and none of them get called. So my hands are really tied. Is this a system level behaviour? Can anyone guide me through this?

***EDIT:***

I forgot to mention that, the button resides in a NSPopover. So, basically, there's a NSButton in the HUD panel. When user clicks the button, a NSPopover will show up, inside which, there's the button to bring up the new window.

Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem. The following solved it:

```
[NSApp endSheet:yourPanel];
[yourPanel orderOut:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But it doesn't solve my problem.. Mine is a little bit tougher, I forgot to mention in the question that the button is in a NSPopover. So, when I click a button, a NSPopover shows up, inside the popover, there's the button to bring th window. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[hudPanel performClose:nil]
```

(in Swift I have to use `self` instead of `nil`). I had a problem using `orderOut` with a popover and it was solved by using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `[hudPanel close]`  after  `[hudPanel orderOut:nil]`

swift: `hudPanel.close()`

from the apple docs:
If the window is the key or main window, the window object immediately behind it is made key or main in its place. Calling orderOut(_:) causes the window to be removed from the screen, but does not cause it to be released. See the close() method for information on when a window is released.

Sometimes the window reappears during window controller inner logic, I think. I have an issue when long pressing keyboard button kills window, but shot keyDown event only hides it on the split second. After using `close` all goes smoothly.